# How to use Clip and Set in Inkscape by filling only the borders of the object, not the interior

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask, graphic-styles

I want to fill the outline of my object with another image. If I use Clip & Set, my object gets all filled.

My current object is a cat:

[image]

The black color should be replaced by an image, the interior of the cat should stay transparent. How to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the fill, if there's one, let the black outline stroke stay. Make a spare copy of your shape, you may need it later.

Select the shape. Goto Path > Stroke to Path. That transforms the outline stroke to filled area.

Use the shape to clip the image. The outline acts as a clipping mask, because it's now a filled area.

An example:

[image]

**Not asked**  Scrap the idea of using Clip > Set. Change the stroke color to white and use Object > Mask > Set. Mask is a way to affect transparency with color, white = fully opaque.

Comment: Look what i get when i use Stroke -> Path 
-> https://imgur.com/a/ZN42o9z

Comment: Your shape has something which isn't normal Inkscape path. Imported stuff? Try at first (=before converting stroke to path ) to convert the shape to ordinary Inkscape path with Path > Object to Path

Comment: You saved my life dude, Thank you very mach